# Argument of type 'DeepPartial<S>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'PreloadedState<S>'

Tags: redux, redux-toolkit

I have `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "1.4.0",` and `"redux": "4.0.5"`
Getting an error with the type of preloadedState in configureStore.ts.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's really likely that you've got multiple conflicting redux dependencies. You can probably resolve this by:

1. Remove the `redux` dependency as it's unnecessary - `@reduxjs/toolkit` will include it for you
2. Purge your node_modules
3. Remove your lock file
4. Reinstall